# How to get 3 legend boxes in scatter graph using coreplot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

```
I am unable to put three legend boxes on the graph.I have tried the following code


     CPTGraph *graph1 = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

        CGFloat legendPadding = -(self.view.bounds.size.width / 8);

        graph1.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(legendPadding, 0.0);  
                        
        CPTLegend *theLegend1 = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph1];

        theLegend1.numberOfColumns = 1;

        theLegend1.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];

        theLegend1.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];

        theLegend1.cornerRadius = 5.0;       


        graph1.legend = theLegend1;     

        graph1.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
        

        CGFloat legendPadding1 = -(self.view.bounds.size.width / 4);


        graph1.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(legendPadding1, 0.0);

where am i going wrong ?

Here is the code for adding plots:

     CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;
    // 2 - Create the three plots
    aaplPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init]autorelease];
    aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
    aaplPlot.identifier = @"MaxWeight";

    CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor magentaColor];
    [graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    googPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init]autorelease];
    googPlot.dataSource = self;
    googPlot.identifier = @"MinWeight";
    CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    [graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    msftPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init]autorelease];
    msftPlot.dataSource = self;
    msftPlot.identifier = @"NormalWeight";

    CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot,msftPlot,googPlot,nil]];
```

I have added this code to add plots .Using the above code i am able to plot only one legend box.but my requirement is to get three legend boxes..where am i doing wrong.Please verify the code and let me know where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've omitted some setup code, the issue is that your graph doesn't have any plots at the time you created the legend. Either create the legend with `+legendWithGraph:` after adding the plots to the graph, or add them to the legend later with the `-addPlot:` or `-insertPlot:atIndex:` methods.

Comment: That's fine. Be sure to move the legend-building code you posted originally to a point after you add the plots to the graph.